# Failure to get Facebook access token for Facebook API management

Tags: facebook, token, facebook-access-token

I want to have access to [FB API](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/api?paipv=0&eav=AfZOm2DalaWAILD0unf7XRhX19s7SGmm08F0nY2m8GrlBJTxaNb9AGz3pHK9jcOidC8&_rdr) not necessary through Facebook app. I've still registered as a developer in Facebook and I made a simple Facebook app. Yet **I still can't get token (access marker). Why?**

[image]

Comment: Did you add the Facebook Login "product" to your app? Not sure if Graph API Explorer is supposed to be able to trigger the authorization process otherwise.